# Find index of element within for loop

Tags: python

Is it possible to make something like this in Python ?

```
a = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
for letter in a:
    print #I want to obtain a[0] or a[1] or a[2]...
```

Thanks in advance. I know the title isn't very explicit but I don't know how to correctly explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `enumerate`.

```
a = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
for idx, letter in enumerate(a):
    print "a[", idx, "] contains the letter", letter
```

Result:

```
a[ 0 ] contains the letter h
a[ 1 ] contains the letter e
a[ 2 ] contains the letter l
a[ 3 ] contains the letter l
a[ 4 ] contains the letter o
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Fast and clean.